# How to set Spacer between with two elements in a row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

How to use Spacer filling between with two elements in a row, let one element at the start of row and another at the end?

```
Row {
    Text("Start")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.SpaceBetween)  // How to set the modifier
    Text("End")
}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `Modifier.SpaceBetween` doesn't exist.

You can use the **`horizontalArrangement`** parameter in the `Row` applying the[**`Arrangement.SpaceBetween`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement#spacebetween).This parameter places children such that they are spaced evenly across the main axis, without free space before the first child or after the last child.

```
Row( modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
    Text("Start")
    Text("End")
}
```

As alternative you can apply the `weight(1f)` to the `Spacer`.
Something like:

```
Row (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text("Start")
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    Text("End")
}
```

[image]

Comment: What if my 'Start' Text is long enough that it reaches till 'End' Text. How to limit 'Start' width to be limited till 'End' starts

Comment: @Ali_Waris In this case you can use `Arrangement.SpaceBetween` applying a `weight` modifier to the first text.

Comment: Why doesn't it work properly when I don't add fillmaxwidth?I was just wondering why

Comment: @NewPartizal Because the `horizontalArrangement` places children according to the available space.

Answer (score 18):

You can use this:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Text("Start")
    Text("End")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The possible horizontal arrangements are following. I added 3 elements for better clarity.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
) {
    TextButtons...
  }
```

[image: Space evenly]

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    TextButtons...
  }
```

[image: Space Between]

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
) {
    TextButtons...
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Also we can set custom space between with

```horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)```