# Horizontal Arrangement not working in Jetpack Compose Row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I follow the official document to learn about Rows.

It's working fine.
It arrange views horizontally and application runs without any issues.

**Problem:**

I want to set horizontalArrangement in Row. **It didn't arrange it.**

**My code:**

```
@Composable
fun SimpleRowArrangement(){
    Row(horizontalArrangement  =  Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom) {
        Text(text = "Row Text 1")
        Text(text = "Row Text 2")
        Text(text = "Row Text 3")
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Apply also the fillMaxWidth modifier

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should apply also the **`fillMaxWidth`** modifier.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
) {
        Text(text = "Row Text 1")
        Text(text = "Row Text 2")
        Text(text = "Row Text 3")
    }
```

[image]

Comment: working fine. In documentation they didn't mention anything. Thanks for your answer

Comment: And if I want one ```Text``` at the start, one ```Text``` at the end of ```Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth)``` So, how to achieve it ?

Comment: @MichaelAbyzov You can use `Arrangement.SpaceBetween`. Check also 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/64433116/2016562

Comment: `VerticalAlignment` doesn't compile.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky the `verticalAlignment` attribute exists. check also the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Row(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical,kotlin.Function1))